# Why the HTML paragraph <P> behaves so oddly on my chrome?

Tags: html

Get an empty HTML, type in this and see its source code on Google Chrome:

```
<p><div>&nbsp;</div>WHY?</p>
```

If you did it like I did, you'll see this in the source:

```
<html>
<head></head><body><p>&nbsp;</p><div>&nbsp;</div>WHY?<p></p>
</body></html>
```

Just in case, [here's a demo using jsbin](http://jsbin.com/iwale4). In that link, you see this:

```
[repeating P]


WHY?
[repeating P]
```

I've added [this jQuery](http://jsbin.com/iwale4/edit) on it:

```
$("p").html("[repeating P]");
```

Remove the whole `<div>` from it, and everything goes back to normal. This small weird unexpected behavior is consistent when adding more things in the `<div>`, and it could be a `<span>` or I guess whatever in there. And it doesn't matter if the HTML is well formated or not.

Anyone knows **why**?

Comment: I found the same problem with `<p><h2>test</h2>
Test</p>`, so I cannot use the p element as a flex item, contrary to all the documentation! Yes, I understand that blocks cannot be inside inlines. But why doesn't CSS simply generate error messages, like other languages?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As a basic explanation, `div` is meant to be a 'box' for layout. A box for holding other things. The `p` element, however, is meant to be for (surprise) a paragraph of text.

Because a `div` (container) was put inside a `p` (inline element), it is (technically) incorrect. Google Chrome (being the standards-slightly-obsessed) browser that it is, it tries to correct this incorrect nesting by adding the extra elements as shown.

The W3C has a (very long) article about these [language specifications](http://www.w3.org/TR/2002/REC-xhtml1-20020801/) on their site, however possibly the best thing to do to check for inconsistencies and potential problems like this is to Validate your written source code. The easiest way to do this is with the [W3C Validator](http://validator.w3.org/).

Comment: to complement this answer, @Syntax Error provided a very good link covering some basic HTML tag usages: http://brainstormsandraves.com/articles/semantics/structure/

Comment: So this utterly defeats the purpose of an inline-block?

Comment: Same thing happens when nesting `<p>` in `<p>`

Answer (score 4):

The paragraph tag is meant to contain text, or more precisely, inline elements.  Chrome interprets a div inside a p as an html malformation and attempts to correct it as well as it can.

Answer (score 1):

I can't find a good source on this so I may be mistaken but I was recently reading about how unclosed p tags are technically valid html (obviously not valid xhtml though) Basically in the right circumstances they will close themselves, just like how a br or hr closes itself without an ending tag. Even if they're not technically valid, they apparently get used that way enough that it's considered acceptable to some of the less civilized crowds. Gross, I know.

I imagine what is happening is Chrome sees your block element (the div) after the p, so it assumes that you were intending the p to self close. I assume that seeing the ending p triggers the same action because to Chrome there is not currently an open p tag by the time it encounters the closing tag.

As a side note - If it didn't bother you to put a div in a p I would suggest reading up on why semantics are so important when it comes to html. I just looked through a few articles - may I suggest this one for a quick read?
http://brainstormsandraves.com/articles/semantics/structure/

Comment: The reason why <p> tags are valid unclosed is that originally <p> was defined as a "new paragraph" marker, rather than p being a container element. Equivalent to <br> being a "new line" marker. You can see so defined in this document from 1992:http://www.w3.org/History/19921103-hypertext/hypertext/WWW/MarkUp/Tags.html and this one from 1993: http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/draft-ietf-iiir-html-01.txt Because there were web pages pre-dating the change and browser parsers have always been as backward compatible as possible with existing web content, it's always stayed possible to use <p> that way.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the link, Syntax dude! And I was going to say something like @Alohci said about `p`, but not as well done. :)

Answer (score 0):

Nesting a `div` in a `p` is invalid HTML. I would guess that Chrome is just trying to correct it for you.

Comment: I hardly ever use `p`... Could you elaborate more? What can we nest inside `p`? Why is it invalid? And, above all, can you point a good guide with basic guide lines on this matter?

Comment: As a basic explanation, `div` is meant to be a 'box' for layout. A box for holding other things. The `p` element, however, is meant to be for (surprise) a paragraph of text.

Comment: `div`s can most certainly be nested inside of `p`s. it may not be recommended, but it is valid.