# CSS Child Selector Issue

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Can anyone tell me how the "Heading" and "Heading 2" are being coloured red in the following example? http://jsfiddle.net/zxfNU/1/

HTML

```
<div id="root">
    <p>
        <p>Test 1</p>

        <h3>Heading</h3>

        <h3>Heading 2</h3>

    </p>
</div>

<h3>Heading 3</h3>
```

CSS

```
div#root > h3
{
    color: red;
}
```

Isn't the CSS only selecting a h3 element if it's under the div, when in fact it's under the p element?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`p` inside `p` is not valid markup. So the result html is:

```
<div id="root">
    <p></p>
    <p>Test 1</p>
    <h3>Heading</h3>       
    <h3>Heading 2</h3>
    <p></p>
</div>
```

As you can see browser fixes the wrong markup to follow the specification.

Comment: When I changed the outer P to a div, it still looks wrong: http://jsfiddle.net/zxfNU/2/

Comment: Ignore me, it works now :). When I select only on div#root it's fine.

Comment: Of course, you're using `div > h3` selector instead of `div#root > h3`

Comment: If you notice, the `</p>` end tag at the bottom just before the `</div>` end tag also creates a paragraph. This is by tradition; see this for more info http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11570902/why-does-a-stray-closing-p-tag-generate-an-empty-paragraph

Comment: As a side note, I thought a P element was just a block element, which means it can contain other block/inline elements? Do all block type elements have their own specific rules like this in how they are treated by the browser?

Comment: @MeshMan: In HTML, `p` is special in that it cannot contain other flow containers (or other block-level elements in terms of CSS). This includes other `p` elements.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of `<p>` use `<div>`, because `<p>` inside `<p>` is not valid markup.

Answer (score 0):

This is because p tag inside a p tag is not a valid Html 
Use Inspect element you will find your html as

```
  <div id="root">
    <p>
        </p><p>Test 1</p>

        <h3>Heading</h3>

        <h3>Heading 2</h3>

    <p></p>
</div>

<h3>Heading 3</h3>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the rendered HTML, e.g. in Firebug:

[image]

That's because you can't put a `p` inside another `p`

@Your edited fiddle:

Now the following HTML is rendered:

[image]

And, as you also changed your CSS to `div > h3`, it's still colored red.