# CSS descendant-versus-child hierarchy not working

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Below is a simple piece of HTML/CSS code, where I put in two URLs:

- The 1st URL (Google) is a child of the div.
- The 2nd URL (Bing) is only a descendant of the div.

Child-selector use implies that only the Google URL should be colored Red.

But in implementation, somehow **both** Google and Bing URLs are Red. (Also, interestingly, when I remove the `<h1>Text</h1>` element, then only the Google URL is colored Red.)

**What is the reason?**

Here is the HTML extract:

```
<div class="mydiv">
    <a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>
    <p>
        <h1>Text</h1>
        <a href="http://www.bing.com">Bing</a>
    </p>
</div>
```

And the CSS extract:

```css
.mydiv > a {
    color:red;
}
```

Comment: because both are child of mydiv

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is kind of tricky.

First of all `<h1>` is a block-element. Next to note is, that `<p>` can only contain inline elements. As soon as a block element is encountered as a child of a `<p>` element, the opened `<p>` is implicitly closed.

So (internally) your HTML snippet is transformed to this (for all I know the closing `</p>` is ignored then):

```
<div class="mydiv">
        <a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>
        <p></p>
        <h1>Text</h1>
        <a href="http://www.bing.com">Bing</a>
</div>
```

Now, as you can see, both `<a>` tags are direct descendants of your `<div>` and so your CSS rule applies to both of them.

The behavior, when removing the `<h1>` tag follows accordingly: Your `<p>` is not implicitly closed. As such the second `<a>` remains a child of `<p>` and the CSS does not apply to it.

I think, what you want to have is best achieved using another `<div>` instead of the `<p>` tag (maybe even `<article>`, `<section>` or similar).

Comment: Clarified! And would a suggestion from this also be to generally avoid using <p> for anything more than one element inside it?

Comment: @boardbite Basically yes. You can, however, use inline elements like `<span>` or `<a>` for styling or linking purposes. But be sure not to insert any block level element, as this will probably break your design.

Comment: Actually, in all major browsers the closing `</p>` tag seems to become its own `p` element: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11570902/why-does-a-stray-closing-p-tag-generate-an-empty-paragraph So you have two `p` elements, one after each `a` element. Trippy! But +1 for a very good explanation.