# Styling <img> in <figure>

Tags: html, css

I can't seem to style an image that is within an figure:

**HTML:**

```
<article>
    <p>

    <figure class="float-right">
        <img src="images/castle1.jpg">
        <figcaption>The castle by day</figcaption>
    </figure> 

    </p>
</article>
```

**CSS:**

```
article p figure img {
    height: 330px;
    width: 500px;
    float: right;
    margin: 10px 20px 20px 20px;
    background-color: green;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
```

You can view the site  [here](http://mayar.abertay.ac.uk/~1204925/coursework/index.php)

Comment: Listen to BoltClock. ALSO, close that img tag for crying out loud. ;)

Comment: @Frankenscarf: It doesn't need to be closed unless the OP is trying to adhere to XML syntax rules. Other than the wayward p element, this appears to be a valid HTML fragment.

Comment: You are correct sir. I keep forgetting that everything made today is made for the future in which doctypes no longer exist. I'ma drink my Ensure and rub some Bengay on my aching joints now.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`p` cannot contain a `figure`. The only content that's allowed in a `p` element is [phrasing content](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-p-element), which `figure` doesn't classify as.

What's actually happening is that your `figure` element is being created as a sibling following your `p` element, and silently closing your opening `<p>` tag (leaving the closing tag hanging... [sort of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11570902/why-does-a-stray-closing-p-tag-generate-an-empty-paragraph)). Since your selector looks for an `img` within a `figure` that's itself within a `p`, but the actual DOM does not reflect this, it won't work.

If you're not using the `p` element for anything else, it should be removed, and your selector changed to:

```
article figure img {
    height: 330px;
    width: 500px;
    float: right;
    margin: 10px 20px 20px 20px;
    background-color: green;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just a Small Change

```
.float-right img {
  height: 330px;
  width: 500px;
  float: right;
  margin: 10px 20px 20px 20px;
  background-color: green;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/LLcbk/)