# CSS: Why a "p" element cascades inside a "li" element, but the opposite does not occur?

Tags: html, css

I mean, imagine this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
      </head>
      <body>
      <style>
           p{
                font-size:2em;
            }


          li{
               font-size:2em;
          }
      </style>

         <p>First Paragraph
             <ul>
                    <li>First list element</li>
                    <li>Paragraph inside a list</li>
                    <li>Third list element</li>
            </ul>
         </p>
        <p>Second Paragraph</p>

      </body>
    </html>
```

The result is:[image]

As you see, the elements does not cascade. I mean, both `p` and `li` keep with 2em of `font-size`.

The same occurs if I exchange

```
<p>First Paragraph</p>
```

for

```
<p><p>First Paragraph</p></p>
```

the result keeps the same. A `p` element inside another `p` element also don't cascade.

But if I do this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
  <style>
    p{
font-size:2em;
}


li{
font-size:2em;
}
  </style>
     <p>First Paragraph</p>
     <ul>
    <li>First list element</li>
    <li><p>Paragraph inside a list</p></li>
    <li>Third list element</li>
     </ul>
     <p>Second Paragraph</p>

  </body>
</html>
```

The result is:

[image]

So...the cascade occurus if a paragraph element is inside a list element (font size of the second element is 2em x 2em), but the opposite case is not true. Why?

Comment: I'm not sure what you expect in the first example. The `p` and `li` don't have  a parent/child relationship.

Comment: Fixed. The result keeps the same.

Comment: You should describe what you regard as the problem, instead of using technical terms like “cascade” in a context where they simply don’t apply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "A p element inside another p element also don't cascade."

That's because a block eleement (the `p` element in this case) can't be inside a `p` element.

When you use `<p><p>First Paragraph</p></p>`, the browser ends the first paragraph where the second starts, and creates a third paragraph from the extra closing tag:

```
<p></p>
<p>First Paragraph</p>
<p></p>
```

The same happens when you try to put the list in the paragraph. The first paragraph ends where the list begins as the list is a block element, so the list is never inside the paragraph.

Comment: The extra closing tag is simply ignored. It does not create any element.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela: If that was correct, where would the third paragraph come from then?

Comment: I stand corrected: browsers actually infer an empty `p` element from a homeless `</p>` end tag, and this is specified as a special case in the HTML5 specification.

Comment: On homeless end tags creating new elements: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11570902/why-does-a-stray-p-end-tag-generate-an-empty-paragraph

Answer (score 1):

The font-size doesn't compound because the rules for HTML state that you can't nest a block-level element inside of a paragraph (which includes a `p` itself). If you look at the rendered HTML in your nested `p` example you'll see it actually looks like:

```
<p></p>
<p>First Paragraph</p>
<p></p>
```