# Why does <div style="clear:both;"></div> breaks a paragraph and adds a new empty paragraph?

Tags: html, css

In following example I have `p.inner` which has its children. I am using "" to "clear" and make "Btn" appear on the right and under the  "― Isaac Newton" which is also on the right.

My original code is:

```
<p class="inner">
    <span class="quote">Gravity explains the motions of the planets, but it cannot explain who sets the planets in motion.</span>

  <span class="nameOfAuthor">― Isaac Newton</span>
  <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    <span class="btn">Btn</span>
</p>
```

But what appear in the inspect element of Chrome Dev Tools is this:

[http://imgur.com/a/DlaQO](https://imgur.com/a/DlaQO)

so here it has closed span.quote after `span.nameOfAuthor` even though `span.btn` was included as child of `span.inner` but it has moved it out of span.inner. Also it has added an empty `<p>` after `span.btn`. Why is that?

This all happens when I add `<div style="clear:both;"></div>` to clear.

Comment: If you're marking up a quote, you should use the blockquote element.

Answer (score 4):

Unlike `span`, which is a phrasing element, `div` and `p` are both flow elements. A `p` cannot contain any flow elements (including other `p` elements), so the presence of the `div` immediately ends the `<p>` start tag. (Phrasing elements and flow elements used to be known in older versions of HTML as "inline elements" and "block-level elements" respectively, but they should no longer be used as they can — and do — create confusion with the same terms as used in CSS.)

The underlying reason the orphaned `</p>` end tag results in the creation of a new paragraph is not known, but suffice it to say that this has been consistent behavior for quite some time now, to the point that [the HTML5 spec mandates it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11570902/why-does-a-stray-p-end-tag-generate-an-empty-paragraph), presumably for legacy reasons.

Comment: ... which is a shame, really. If the browsers were allowed to do whatever they liked for error handling, all those web developers would have had to work much harder at being error free, to make their websites cross-browsers compliant.