# Why does inline-block behave differently inside a p vs inside a div?

Tags: html, css

My understanding was that elements styled with `display:inline-block` would be laid out internally as a block but treated as an inline element in whatever container they are inside.  That seems to be true if they're inside a `li` or a `div` or a bunch of other things; but if they're inside a `p` it's different, for reasons unclear to me.  Consider the following example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<p>Test1<table style="display:inline-block"><tr><td>x</td></tr></table>Test1</p>
<div>Test2<table style="display:inline-block"><tr><td>x</td></tr></table>Test2</div>
<p>Test3<span style="display:inline-block"><table><tr><td>x</td></tr></table></span>Test3</p>
<div>Test4<span style="display:inline-block"><table><tr><td>x</td></tr></table></span>Test4</div>
```

Here the first two lines have a table styled `display:inline-block` inside (respectively) a `p` and a `div`.  The next two have the table inside a `span` that has inline-block styling, again inside a `p` and a `div`.  In Test2 and Test4, the `div` cases, the whole thing shows up on a single line (as I would expect for all of them).  In Test1 the supposedly inline-block element is laid out preceded by a line break, and in Test3 the supposedly inline-block element is both preceded and followed by a line break.

Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the classic case of flow elements not belonging in a `p` element manifesting in two interesting ways. To preface: a `p` element cannot contain flow elements, including `table`. See the [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-p-element). Such flow elements are placed as following siblings of the `p` element instead. So:

1. `<p><table></table></p>` is really `<p></p><table></table><p></p>`, and
2. `<p><span><table></table></span></p>` is really `<p><span></span></p><table></table><p></p>`.

(The reason the stray `</p>` end tag is matched with a new `<p>` start tag in both cases is explained in [Why does a stray </p> end tag generate an empty paragraph?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11570902/why-does-a-stray-p-end-tag-generate-an-empty-paragraph))

You already know the expected behavior when the containing element is a `div`, so we'll just focus on Test1 and Test3 with the `p` element.

In Test1, the inline-block element is preceded by a line break because it's in a new paragraph that follows the `p`. (Note that displaying a `table` element as inline-block actually simply causes that `table` element to generate an anonymous table box to contain its descendants — which is why the table layout appears to be preserved.) The following "Test1" text flows alongside it because it's in the same anonymous paragraph and on the same line as the inline-block.

Note that the paragraph generated by matching the stray `</p>` end tag with its own start tag does not actually enclose that text. This behavior is described in the same question I link to above.

In Test3, the `p` element is able to contain the inline-block as it is a `span` element. However, the `p` element ends right where the `table` element starts, so the inline-block `span` is fully enclosed within the `p` element and does not contain the `table` (in fact, it's completely empty). So the `table` appears on its own line, its layout intact, and the following "Test3" text appears on yet another line following the `table`, because tables are block-level by default and as such never appear on the same line as any other elements (including inlines).

Also note that all of this behavior is very well-defined (in the respective specifications), and that while a `p` element cannot contain a `table` element, everything in Test1 leading up to but not including the `</p>` end tag is technically valid HTML. It just doesn't behave as you might have expected.

Answer (score 3):

The `table` element isn't allowed as a child of `p`. The [p element](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/single-page.html#the-p-element) has a [phrasing content](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/single-page.html#phrasing-content) model, and a `table` isn't phrasing content.

Answer (score 0):

**Update: THIS ANSWER IS OUTDATED! It is for HTML4, not HTML5.**

`The P element represents a paragraph. It cannot contain block-level elements (including P itself).` [source](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#h-9.3.1).

A table is a block element...so this might not the precise answer but it is the fundamental issue of your code sample.

Comment: That's from the html4 spec, and OP's using html5.

Comment: That is true. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`p - Paragraph` is a block level element and it can contain only inline elements, although it is a block level element.

For more info, refer to the phrasing model of `p` element [here](http://w3c.github.io/html/single-page.html#phrasing-content-2)

Comment: Yeah, the quote is irrelevant sorry, I am gonna edit it. The issue is with phrasing model as provided by Michael Coker.