# CSS display:inline is not working

Tags: html, css

I saw that there are many questions looking like this one but can't find a solution yet.

My HTML code:

```html
<p class="ref" style="display:inline">
<p class="mini-caps">albums</p>: 
  Scum
  (1987) ; 
  Bootlegged in Japan
  (1998)
</p>
<p class="ref">
<p class="mini-caps">compilation </p>: 
  Noise for Music’s Sake 
  (2 CD, 2003)
</p>
<p class="ref">
  <p class="mini-caps">album</p>: 
  Illmatic 
  (1994)
</p>
```

I tried to style p.ref with display:inline with no success.

The output I would like to have:

> albums : Scum (1987) ; Bootlegged in Japan (1998)
>
> compilation  : Noise for Music’s Sake (2 CD, 2003)
>
> album : Illmatic (1994)

Comment: inline on all the `mini-caps`

Comment: Nested paragraphs are not valid, and it's generally not advisable to make block-level elements inline. Just use spans.

Comment: I looked at your question again and can't glean your intent. You seem to have an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) happenin'. Why are you not just using basic, unstyled paragraphs for each item? If you want to group them for styling, wrap the album and compilation paragraph pairs in a div.

Comment: The thing is that I need to copy the layout/display of an existing book in HTML. And I need to add style to different elements in order to do that. But I try with little iterations/tests without knowing if it's the good way or not since I didn't practice so much HTML/CSS.

Comment: You can’t actually nest the `p` elements, at least in HTML mode: they are auto-closed before opening tag of any non-phrasing element (“block element” in HTML4 terms) and the next paragraph ends up being a sibling of the previous one, not its child. Don’t rely on the markup you write, always check the DOM that browser constructs from it. Also, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11570902/why-does-a-stray-p-end-tag-generate-an-empty-paragraph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why the use of the p tags? You can properly do this with div's and span's.

```
<div class="ref">
    <span class="mini-caps">albums</span>: 
    <span>Scum (1987) ; Bootlegged in Japan (1998)</span>
</div>
<div class="ref">
    <span class="mini-caps">compilation </span>: 
    <span>Noise for Music’s Sake (2 CD, 2003)</span>
</div>
<div class="ref">
    <span class="mini-caps">album</span>: 
    <span>Illmatic (1994)</span>
</div>
```

See https://jsfiddle.net/1r9Lu6y3/6/

Hope this helps

BTW: Illmatic album is sooo good!

Comment: Frankly  a `dl/dt/dd` structure might be ideal - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dl

Comment: @KSoze your welcome. Regarding your question could have a code example? I'm not quite following.

Comment: @NickVanLoocke sorry I deleted my comment, it's working fine finally :) Thank you.