# Select all the <p> elements that contain only a <br> element inside

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have the following HTML code, with no control over it:

```
<p>this is visible</p>

<p>&nbsp;</p>

<p></p>

<p>
<br>
</p>
```

I need to hide all the p elements with no text inside. 
So far, using this script I remove everything except this one:

```
<p>
</br>
</p>
```

This is the script I'm using:

```
   $("p").filter( function() {

      var html = $(this).html();

      if(html == '' || html == '&nbsp;' || html == '<br>')
          return true;

   }).addClass('emptyP');
```

Comment: Well that `</br>` is going to be ignored by the browser, I bet, as it's meaningless in HTML. Have you logged what the script finds in the elements?

Comment: you can try $("p>br") and for each of these elements you can just call parent to get the p element

Comment: `I need to hide all the p elements with no text inside` could you use [.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/)? It would simplify your logic quite a bit as it would not return html entities

Comment: @Pointy: Actually, despite being a syntax error, [</br> is functionally equivalent to <br> in all browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11570902/why-does-a-stray-p-end-tag-generate-an-empty-paragraph#comment15315338_11570988). A typo that, serendipitously, works.

Comment: @BoltClock really?  A *closing* tag? I know that `<br/>` works but interpreting `</br>` as `<br>` doesn't seem like it'd do anybody any favors. However I should not be surprised; my personal theory is that a good portion of such behaviors were hacks introduced by ancient IE versions to make noob web developers in 1999 think IE worked better than Netscape :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to hide all the `p's` with no text, you can use [jQuery.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) as follows.

```js
$("p").filter( function() {
  return !$(this).text().trim();
}).addClass('emptyP');
```

```css
.emptyP {display:none}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>this is visible</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p></p>
<p><br/></p>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Nikhil it works. I don't know why I haven't thought about that. I will accept it in 2 minutes.

Comment: @FlorinSimion - No worries. Can happen. Glad to help you :)